# Sign of $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ in a right neighbourhood of $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x}=0$$
Because of the squeeze theorem used with inequality
$$0 \leq \left|x \sin \frac{1}{x}\right| \leq |x|$$
But I can't prove if the limits
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} x \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
Approach $0$ from the right or from the left, since if I'm not wrong the function $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ changes sign infinitely many times in a deleted neighbourhood of $x=0$; can someone help me?

I thought that for $x\to 0^+$ the sign of $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ is determined only by $\sin \frac{1}{x}$, so I will analyze the behaviour of $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\to 0^+$ for now: it is $\sin \frac{1}{x}>0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{k\pi} < x_k <\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, and for $k\to\infty$ it is $x_k \to 0^+$.

So for all $\varepsilon>0$ it exists $K_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that for all $k>K_{\varepsilon}$ it is $x_k\in(0,\varepsilon)$; this means that the sequence of the values for which $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is positive is in a right neighbourhood of $x=0$, and this proves that $x \sin \frac{1}{x} \to 0^+$ for $x\to 0^+$.

A similar approach for $x \to 0^-$ by considering the behaviour of $x_k$ for $k\to-\infty$ can show that $x \sin \frac{1}{x} \to 0^-$ for $x\to0^-$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: If the usual limit exists, the left- and right-hand limits also exist and are equal to the usual limit.

Answer (score 1):

Any neighborhood of $x=0$ contains negative and positive values of $f$ (left and right).

Comment: To see this, take $x = \frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Thanks for your answer, the doubt come from the evaluation of the limit of $\ln \left(x \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)$ as $x \to 0^+$; so it must be $x \sin \frac{1}{x} >0$ for $x \to 0^+$ for that limit to make sense, am I missing something or that can be evaluated even if the argument of the logarithm changes sign infinitely many times?

Comment: @ZaWarudo: you are missing that the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

In any case

$$-1\le \sin \frac{1}{x}\le 1 \implies 0\le \left| \sin \frac{1}{x}\right|\le 1$$

and this suffices to obtain

$$0 \leq \left|x \sin \frac{1}{x}\right| =|x|\cdot\left| \sin \frac{1}{x}\right|\leq |x|$$

and conclude by squeeze theorem both for left and right limit.